# Google Apps Scripts - For Loop Issue works on false statement instead of true

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
/** -- For Loop to start pairing VIN numbers to parts list -- **/
  console.log('CompleteVIN: ');
  console.log(completeVIN);
  console.log(completeVIN[1].length);

  console.log('CompleteParts: ');
  console.log(completeParts);
  console.log(completeParts[1].length);

  var vinPartsCombine = [];

  /** For loop */
  for (j = 0; j < completeVIN[1].length; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < completeParts[0].length; i++){    
      if (completeVIN[1][j] === completeParts[1][i]) {
        vinPartsCombine.push(completeVIN[0][j],completeParts[0][i]);
      };
    };
  };
  console.log(completeVIN[1][j] === completeParts[1][i]);
  console.log(vinPartsCombine);
```

Result:

```
CompleteVIN: 
[ [ [ 'KG257653' ],
    [ 'KG250444' ],
    [ 'K1239114' ],
    [ 'FG160157' ],
    [ 'LKA41783' ],
    [ 'LKB72564' ] ],
  [ [ 7653 ],
    [ 444 ],
    [ 9114 ],
    [ 'Estimate_to_Repair' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit' ] ] ]
6
CompleteParts: 
[ [ [ 'Repl LT Side bracket' ],
    [ 'Repl LT Filler panel US built' ],
    [ 'Repl LT H\'lamp bracket' ],
    [ 'Repl LT Fender' ],
    [ 'Repl LT Nameplate "SILVERADO"' ],
    [ 'Repl Bumper assy single' ],
    [ 'Repl Cover Car' ],
    [ 'Repl Cover Car' ],
    [ 'Repl Applique upper w/o special trim' ],
    [ 'Repl Corrosion protection primer' ],
    [ 'Repl Cover Car' ],
    [ 'Replace LT Fender (Aftermarket)' ],
    [ 'Replace LT Nameplate "SILVERADO"' ],
    [ 'Repl LT Lower molding' ],
    [ 'Repl LT End cap w/o blind spot' ],
    [ 'Repl LT Side extn w/o extended frame' ],
    [ 'Repl LT Bumper outer support' ],
    [ 'Repl LT Bumper inner support' ],
    [ 'Repl LT Bumper' ],
    [ 'Repl Aerial assembly' ],
    [ 'Repl Cover Car' ],
    [ 'Repl Corrosion protection primer' ],
    [ 'Repl Cover Car' ],
    [ 'Repl Cover Car' ],
    [ 'Repl Corrosion protection primer' ] ],
  [ [ 7653 ],
    [ 7653 ],
    [ 7653 ],
    [ 7653 ],
    [ 7653 ],
    [ 7653 ],
    [ 7653 ],
    [ 444 ],
    [ 9114 ],
    [ 9114 ],
    [ 9114 ],
    [ 'Estimate_to_Repair' ],
    [ 'Estimate_to_Repair' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit' ],
    [ 'transit' ],
    [ 'transit' ] ] ]
25
true
[]
```

My for loop will not work how I want it, but when I change the condition to != it runs, but not the output I want.

- CompleteVIN array consists of VIN #'s and Source Names
- CompleteParts array consists of Parts and Source Names

The for loop is to search each array by source when source match then it would push it to the vinPartsCombine array so that it pairs it with the vin number and parts description. Until source does not match then it would switch to the next vin number element with a new source name.

```js
completeVIN = [[[ 'KG257653' ],
    [ 'KG250444' ],
    [ 'K1239114' ],
    [ 'FG160157' ],
    [ 'LKA41783' ],
    [ 'LKB72564' ]],
    [[ 7653 ],
    [ 444 ],
    [ 9114 ],
    [ 'Estimate_to_Repair' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit' ]]];
    
    
CompleteParts = [ [ [ 'Repl LT Side bracket' ],
    [ 'Repl LT Filler panel US built' ],
    [ 'Repl LT H\'lamp bracket' ],
    [ 'Repl LT Fender' ],
    [ 'Repl LT Nameplate "SILVERADO"' ],
    [ 'Repl Bumper assy single' ],
    [ 'Repl Cover Car' ],
    [ 'Repl Cover Car' ],
    [ 'Repl Applique upper w/o special trim' ],
    [ 'Repl Corrosion protection primer' ],
    [ 'Repl Cover Car' ],
    [ 'Replace LT Fender (Aftermarket)' ],
    [ 'Replace LT Nameplate "SILVERADO"' ],
    [ 'Repl LT Lower molding' ],
    [ 'Repl LT End cap w/o blind spot' ],
    [ 'Repl LT Side extn w/o extended frame' ],
    [ 'Repl LT Bumper outer support' ],
    [ 'Repl LT Bumper inner support' ],
    [ 'Repl LT Bumper' ],
    [ 'Repl Aerial assembly' ],
    [ 'Repl Cover Car' ],
    [ 'Repl Corrosion protection primer' ],
    [ 'Repl Cover Car' ],
    [ 'Repl Cover Car' ],
    [ 'Repl Corrosion protection primer' ] ],
  [ [ 7653 ],
    [ 7653 ],
    [ 7653 ],
    [ 7653 ],
    [ 7653 ],
    [ 7653 ],
    [ 7653 ],
    [ 444 ],
    [ 9114 ],
    [ 9114 ],
    [ 9114 ],
    [ 'Estimate_to_Repair' ],
    [ 'Estimate_to_Repair' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit' ],
    [ 'transit' ],
    [ 'transit' ] ] ];

var vinPartsCombine = [];

  /** For loop */
  for (j = 0; j < completeVIN[1].length; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < CompleteParts[1].length; i++){    
      if (completeVIN[1][j] == CompleteParts[1][i]) {
        vinPartsCombine.push(completeVIN[0][j],CompleteParts[0][i]);
      };
    };
  };
  console.log(completeVIN[1][j] === CompleteParts[1][i]);
  console.log(vinPartsCombine);
```

Comment: Is it simply because you wrote `completeParts[0].length` instead of `completeParts[1].length` (the "1")?

Comment: I did that in the first loop because I want my j value to cycle through 6 times in my completeVIN array. since there is only 6 values in that one, or 6 source to look through. While my parts array has 25 values and source is repeated in that array so there should be multiple matches. per each source value. The 1 is the source column, but that wouldn't matter since [0] or [1] are the same length. If I were to just use completeParts.length then the length would be 2.

Comment: Alright makes sense. I cleaned the log a little to make it more readable. I would also suggest you to provide a (still relevant) exemple with less items just to make it easier to read / reason about

Comment: Okay I think I recreated the same issue in the snippet. Thanks for the help guys appreciate it. The only thing is that google scripts uses (.push) I would have used append() in JavaScript not sure if .push would work here or if I should switch it to append() instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Figured it out. I had made it more complicated initially by having elements inside elements....In example: [0][0][0]. Anyway here is what I did.

```js
completeVIN = [[[ 'KG257653' ],
    [ 'KG250444' ],
    [ 'K1239114' ],
    [ 'FG160157' ],
    [ 'LKA41783' ],
    [ 'LKB72564' ]],
    [[ 7653 ],
    [ 444 ],
    [ 9114 ],
    [ 'Estimate_to_Repair' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit' ]]];
    
    
completeParts = [ [ [ 'Repl LT Side bracket' ],
    [ 'Repl LT Filler panel US built' ],
    [ 'Repl LT H\'lamp bracket' ],
    [ 'Repl LT Fender' ],
    [ 'Repl LT Nameplate "SILVERADO"' ],
    [ 'Repl Bumper assy single' ],
    [ 'Repl Cover Car' ],
    [ 'Repl Cover Car' ],
    [ 'Repl Applique upper w/o special trim' ],
    [ 'Repl Corrosion protection primer' ],
    [ 'Repl Cover Car' ],
    [ 'Replace LT Fender (Aftermarket)' ],
    [ 'Replace LT Nameplate "SILVERADO"' ],
    [ 'Repl LT Lower molding' ],
    [ 'Repl LT End cap w/o blind spot' ],
    [ 'Repl LT Side extn w/o extended frame' ],
    [ 'Repl LT Bumper outer support' ],
    [ 'Repl LT Bumper inner support' ],
    [ 'Repl LT Bumper' ],
    [ 'Repl Aerial assembly' ],
    [ 'Repl Cover Car' ],
    [ 'Repl Corrosion protection primer' ],
    [ 'Repl Cover Car' ],
    [ 'Repl Cover Car' ],
    [ 'Repl Corrosion protection primer' ] ],
  [ [ 7653 ],
    [ 7653 ],
    [ 7653 ],
    [ 7653 ],
    [ 7653 ],
    [ 7653 ],
    [ 7653 ],
    [ 444 ],
    [ 9114 ],
    [ 9114 ],
    [ 9114 ],
    [ 'Estimate_to_Repair' ],
    [ 'Estimate_to_Repair' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit (1)' ],
    [ 'transit' ],
    [ 'transit' ],
    [ 'transit' ] ] ];

var vinPartsCombine = [];

  /** For loop */
  for (j = 0; j < completeVIN[1].length; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < completeParts[1].length; i++){  
      /** 
      console.log(completeVIN[1][j]);
      console.log(completeParts[1][i]);
      console.log(typeof(completeVIN[1][j]));
      console.log(typeof(completeParts[1][i]));
      */ 

      console.log(completeVIN[1][j][0] == completeParts[1][i][0]);

      if (completeVIN[1][j][0] == completeParts[1][i][0]) {
        vinPartsCombine.push([completeVIN[0][j][0],completeParts[0][i][0]]);
      };
    };
  };
  /** 
  console.log(completeVIN[1][j] === completeParts[1][i]);
  console.log(typeof(completeVIN[1][0][0]));
  */
  console.log(vinPartsCombine);
```

Answer (score 1):

First Function builds a couple of tables on a spreadsheet that I used to figure out what was going on.  The second function uses those tables from the spreadsheet to summarize the data I think the way you wanted it by pivoting the data.

```
function buildtablescript() {
  const completeVin = [[['KG257653'], ['KG250444'], ['K1239114'], ['FG160157'], ['LKA41783'], ['LKB72564']], [[7653], [444], [9114], ['Estimate_to_Repair'], ['transit (1)'], ['transit']]];
  const completeParts = [[['Repl LT Side bracket'], ['Repl LT Filler panel US built'], ['Repl LT H\'lamp bracket'], ['Repl LT Fender'], ['Repl LT Nameplate "SILVERADO"'], ['Repl Bumper assy single'], ['Repl Cover Car'], ['Repl Cover Car'], ['Repl Applique upper w/o special trim'], ['Repl Corrosion protection primer'], ['Repl Cover Car'], ['Replace LT Fender (Aftermarket)'], ['Replace LT Nameplate "SILVERADO"'], ['Repl LT Lower molding'], ['Repl LT End cap w/o blind spot'], ['Repl LT Side extn w/o extended frame'], ['Repl LT Bumper outer support'], ['Repl LT Bumper inner support'], ['Repl LT Bumper'], ['Repl Aerial assembly'], ['Repl Cover Car'], ['Repl Corrosion protection primer'], ['Repl Cover Car'], ['Repl Cover Car'], ['Repl Corrosion protection primer']], [[7653], [7653], [7653], [7653], [7653], [7653], [7653], [444], [9114], [9114], [9114], ['Estimate_to_Repair'], ['Estimate_to_Repair'], ['transit (1)'], ['transit (1)'], ['transit (1)'], ['transit (1)'], ['transit (1)'], ['transit (1)'], ['transit (1)'], ['transit (1)'], ['transit (1)'], ['transit'], ['transit'], ['transit']]];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet4');
  sh.getDataRange().setFontWeight('normal').setBackground('#ffffff');
  sh.clearContents();
  sh.getRange(1, 1).setValue('CompleteVINs:').setFontWeight('bold').setBackground('lightyellow');
  let nr = sh.getLastRow() + 1;
  sh.getRange(nr, 1, completeVin[0].length, completeVin[0][0].length).setValues(completeVin[0]).setHorizontalAlignment('left');
  sh.getRange(nr, 2, completeVin[1].length, completeVin[1][0].length).setValues(completeVin[1]).setHorizontalAlignment('left');
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  nr = sh.getLastRow() + 1;
  sh.getRange(nr, 1).setValue('CompleteParts:').setFontWeight('bold').setBackground('lightyellow');
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  nr = sh.getLastRow() + 1;
  sh.getRange(nr, 1, completeParts[0].length, completeParts[0][0].length).setValues(completeParts[0]).setHorizontalAlignment('left');
  sh.getRange(nr, 2, completeParts[1].length, completeParts[1][0].length).setValues(completeParts[1]).setHorizontalAlignment('left');
}
```

The table produced by the above function:

| CompleteVINs: |  |
| --- | --- |
| KG257653 | 7653 |
| KG250444 | 444 |
| K1239114 | 9114 |
| FG160157 | Estimate_to_Repair |
| LKA41783 | transit (1) |
| LKB72564 | transit |

| CompleteParts: |  |
| --- | --- |
| Repl LT Side bracket | 7653 |
| Repl LT Filler panel US built | 7653 |
| Repl LT H'lamp bracket | 7653 |
| Repl LT Fender | 7653 |
| Repl LT Nameplate "SILVERADO" | 7653 |
| Repl Bumper assy single | 7653 |
| Repl Cover Car | 7653 |
| Repl Cover Car | 444 |
| Repl Applique upper w/o special trim | 9114 |
| Repl Corrosion protection primer | 9114 |
| Repl Cover Car | 9114 |
| Replace LT Fender (Aftermarket) | Estimate_to_Repair |
| Replace LT Nameplate "SILVERADO" | Estimate_to_Repair |
| Repl LT Lower molding | transit (1) |
| Repl LT End cap w/o blind spot | transit (1) |
| Repl LT Side extn w/o extended frame | transit (1) |
| Repl LT Bumper outer support | transit (1) |
| Repl LT Bumper inner support | transit (1) |
| Repl LT Bumper | transit (1) |
| Repl Aerial assembly | transit (1) |
| Repl Cover Car | transit (1) |
| Repl Corrosion protection primer | transit (1) |
| Repl Cover Car | transit |
| Repl Cover Car | transit |
| Repl Corrosion protection primer | transit |

Now the function that summarizes the data:

```
function pivotscript() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet4');
  const cVrow = sh.createTextFinder('CompleteVINs:').findAll()[0].getRow();
  const cProw = sh.createTextFinder('CompleteParts:').findAll()[0].getRow();
  const cVvs = sh.getRange(cVrow + 1, 1, cProw - cVrow - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const cPvs = sh.getRange(cProw + 1, 1, sh.getLastRow() - cProw - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const pObj = { pA: [], vA: [] };
  cVvs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (!pObj.hasOwnProperty(r[1])) {
      pObj[r[1]] = {vin:r[0],partA:[]};
      pObj.pA.push(r[1]);
    } else {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Vin Table has duplicates');
      return;
    }
  });//build the table
  cPvs.forEach((r, i) => {if (pObj.hasOwnProperty(r[1])) {pObj[r[1]].partA.push(r[0]);}});
  let html = '<style>th,td{border:1px solid black;padding:5px;}</style><table><tr><th>Property</th><th>Vin</th><th>Parts</th></tr>';
  pObj.pA.forEach((p,i)=>{
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',p,pObj[p].vin,pObj[p].partA.join('<br />'));
  });
  html+='</table>'
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(800).setHeight(600),'Summary');
}
```

Summary Table Dialog:

[image]